# How can I save an audio blob in extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, blob, indexeddb

I record audio from the user's microphone in the extension. I need the last entry to be saved even after the extension is closed (suddenly the user accidentally closes the extension). How and where is it best stored?

Now I save an audio blob in chrome local storage. But there is a problem with working with Vuex.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
            try {
                chrome.storage.local.set({
                    'calibrateAudio': audio
                }, function() {
                    console.log('chromAPI: ' + audio);
                    resolve(audio);
                });
            } catch (err) {
                reject(new Error(err))
            }
        })
```

I would like to get advice on how best to store audio recording locally. It is desirable that the data be returned using a getter, without return functions.

Comment: You also can use IndexedDB

Comment: Can it's possible to use it with Chrome Extension and Vuex?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in my chrome extension. I recommend you to check this driver for IndexedDB: [Dexie](http://dexie.org/)